# Greek characters with times font (utf8 input encoding)

Tags: fonts, greek

I am despairing trying to solve the following problem. When compiling the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[document]{ucs}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek, english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenx}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}       % T2A is Cyrillic
\newcommand{\grrk}{\selectlanguage{polutonikogreek}\fontencoding{LGR}}
\newcommand{\ee}{\selectlanguage{english}\fontencoding{T1}}
 \begin{document}
\grrk  ἀφιέναι \ee `to send off, discharge', with infinitive: `suffer, permit'
\end{document}
```

Running pdflatex, I get the following error:

```
(C:\Users\rvw\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\unicode\ucsencs.def
fontencoding LGR patched
) (C:\Users\rvw\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\grtimes\lgrptm.fd)Running miktex-makemf.exe...
miktex-makemf: The grtm source file could not be found.
Running hbf2gf.exe...
hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.0)
Couldn't find `grtm.cfg'
miktex-maketfm: No creation rule for font grtm10.
! Font LGR/ptm/m/n/10=grtm10 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not foun
d.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.10 \grrk
            ἀφιέναι \ee `to send off, discharge', with infinitive: `...
```

Everything is all right if I do not include `\usepackage{times}`.

I understand the problem has to to with my font installation. But I am completely lost trying to understand how to solve it.

I am using MikTeX, all packages updated, on a win7 machine.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: Your example 'works for me' using TeX Live 2011 on Windows: I suspect you may be missing some parts of the required font files.

Comment: The [times](http://ctan.org/pkg/times) package is obsolete. Either use [mathptmx](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathptmx) or [txfonts](http://ctan.org/pkg/txfonts).

Comment: Using mathptmx doesn't change anything. Yes, I seem to be missing some part of the font files. But how do I get them?

Comment: Let me clarify my question. Where do I find a short recipe that will enable me to just rebuild my font directory in such a way that it will be complete?

Comment: @Joseph: Could you please show the (pdflatex) log-file of your compilation so that I can see the fonts used? (I get errors on miktex too but I don't want to waste a lot of time to track down the fonts.)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Of course: I'll e-mail directly (it's a bit long for a comment)

Comment: @Joseph @Ruprecht: The relevant line in Josephs log-file is `LaTeX Font Info:    No file LGRptm.fd. on input line 10.`. So latex falls back to cmr. In miktex LGRptm.fd exists (from the `grtimes` package) but as the readme of this packages says the fonts themselves are not provided. Ruprecht: Do you want to use a "times greek" font, or would it be enough if the non-greek text uses times and greek uses cmr?

Answer (score 1):

The code works on TeX Live 2011. It seems that MiKTeX does not have some fonts.

Since you use UTF-8 encoding, I advise you to use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX solution. It is more modern and you can use Times New Roman on Windows or Linux Libertine on TeX distributions.

Example:

```
% XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{polyglossia} % replacement of babel
\newcommand{\grrk}{\selectlanguage{greek}} % not necessary
\newcommand{\ee}{\selectlanguage{english}} % not necessary
 \begin{document}
\grrk  ἀφιέναι \ee `to send off, discharge', with infinitive: `suffer, permit'
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the minimal example worked! In addition, txfonts, which at the beginning did not change anything, now works. This is either because running that example somehow led to the generation of the missing files, or because I did not wait long enough for MikTex to load txfonts before.  I cannot at the moment use XeTex or LuaTex because the transliteration of cyrillic I am using will not work with those. 

In any case, thank you all a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert on fontencoding and this is too long for a comment, but if you comment out the `\ee` command it works.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[combine,document]{ucs}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek, english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenx}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}       % T2A is Cyrillic
%\newcommand{\ee}{\selectlanguage{english}\fontencoding{T1}}
\newcommand{\grrk}{\selectlanguage{polutonikogreek}\fontencoding{LGR}}
 \begin{document}
\grrk  ἀφιέναι 
\end{document}
```

I have used the `combined` option of `UCS`. If you uncomment you will get more meaningful errors, such as `\textpsili` unavailable in encoding `T1`.