# how can we write in Greek with computer modern font

Tags: fonts, greek, computer-modern

How can we write Greek documents (i.e. in the Greek language) having the computer modern font? What code do we have to write?  I'd like to note that I don't want to include some Greek letters, but I'd like to write an entire Greek text.

Comment: [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69901/how-to-typeset-greek-letters/69908#69908) and [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37413/greek-characters-with-times-font-utf8-input-encoding/37437#37437) may help you.

Comment: @Manuel Thank you for your help, but I would like to write the greek text entering greek caracters and the font would be like this is one from the first site that you gave me above. Let's say I would like to write φύσις and the written word would be like that one. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I don't understad you, but the first link lets you write φύσις.

Comment: Are you perhaps asking if Computer Modern itself has support for Greek as a means of communication (as opposed to its use in mathematics)?  Is this a question about the font, or is it a question about LaTeX?

Comment: @SeanAllred It's more a question about the font. I want to write in Greek (to produce a Greek text, like having my keyboard in Greek), not by doing it like the manuals seen above. Also, if you know another font that can offer the same beautiful result just like this one font, as an alternative option, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: @giannis Without precise information about your operating system and TeX distribution, it's difficult to say more.

Comment: @egreg I'll try to give some info: my OP is Windows 7 and I use MikTeX 2.9 (with TeXworks).

Comment: @giannis Try copy and paste from the updated answer; but you should first update your distribution. Use the MiKTeX wizard.

Comment: I've updated my MiKTeX distribution, and now i notice this message: "! Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined
(inputenc)                in inputencoding `utf8'."

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's not at all difficult, if you have an up-to-date TeX distribution.

The text is from [http://el.wikipedia.org/wiki/Αθήνα](http://el.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%91%CE%B8%CE%AE%CE%BD%CE%B1)

### Version for TeX Live 2013 and later

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}

\begin{document}

Η Αθήνα (Ἀθῆναι στα αρχαία ελληνικά και την καθαρεύουσα) είναι η
πρωτεύουσα της Ελλάδας. Επίσης είναι η έδρα της Περιφέρειας
Αττικής. Βρίσκεται στη Στερεά (Κεντρική) Ελλάδα και αποτελεί εύρωστο
οικονομικό, πολιτιστικό και διοικητικό κέντρο της χώρας. Πήρε το όνομά
της από τη θεά Αθηνά που ήταν και η προστάτιδά της. Η Αθήνα σήμερα
είναι μία σύγχρονη πόλη αλλά και διάσημη, καθώς στην αρχαιότητα ήταν
πανίσχυρη πόλη-κράτος και σημαντικότατο κέντρο πολιτισμού· θεωρείται η
ιστορικότερη πόλη της Ευρώπης μαζί με τη Ρώμη. Είναι γνωστή σε όλο τον
κόσμο για τα ιστορικά της μνημεία που διασώθηκαν,έστω και μερικώς, στο
πέρασμα των αιώνων. Επίνειο της ιστορικής πόλης είναι το λιμάνι του
Πειραιά. Πολιούχος της Πόλης των Αθηνών είναι ο Άγιος Διονύσιος ο
Αρεοπαγίτης.

\end{document}
```

### Version for TeX Live 2012

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[LGRx,T1]{fontenc} % or OT1 instead of T1
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}

\begin{document}

Η Αθήνα (Ἀθῆναι στα αρχαία ελληνικά και την καθαρεύουσα) είναι η
πρωτεύουσα της Ελλάδας. Επίσης είναι η έδρα της Περιφέρειας
Αττικής. Βρίσκεται στη Στερεά (Κεντρική) Ελλάδα και αποτελεί εύρωστο
οικονομικό, πολιτιστικό και διοικητικό κέντρο της χώρας. Πήρε το όνομά
της από τη θεά Αθηνά που ήταν και η προστάτιδά της. Η Αθήνα σήμερα
είναι μία σύγχρονη πόλη αλλά και διάσημη, καθώς στην αρχαιότητα ήταν
πανίσχυρη πόλη-κράτος και σημαντικότατο κέντρο πολιτισμού· θεωρείται η
ιστορικότερη πόλη της Ευρώπης μαζί με τη Ρώμη. Είναι γνωστή σε όλο τον
κόσμο για τα ιστορικά της μνημεία που διασώθηκαν,έστω και μερικώς, στο
πέρασμα των αιώνων. Επίνειο της ιστορικής πόλης είναι το λιμάνι του
Πειραιά. Πολιούχος της Πόλης των Αθηνών είναι ο Άγιος Διονύσιος ο
Αρεοπαγίτης.

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Version for pre 2012 TeX Live

With an older TeX system (but I recommend you to upgrade) you get the same result with the following code.

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek]{babel}

\begin{document}
Η Αθήνα (Ἀθῆναι στα αρχαία ελληνικά και την καθαρεύουσα) είναι η
...

\end{document}
```

### Notes about the answer

The original answer did not have the first part, because it was written when the current release of TeX Live was labeled 2012.

Comment: Thank you very very much. I didn't know such a thing. I really think that you're saving me from so much time!

Comment: when I've tried just the same code as yours i've seen this error message:

Comment: ! Package fontenc Error: Encoding file `lgrxenc.def' not found.
(fontenc)                
You might have misspelt the name of the encoding.

Comment: @giannis This means you don't have an up-to-date TeX distribution. Can you add to your question what it is? However I've added a workaround to use until you upgrade.

Comment: what is an up-to-date TeX distribution? another version of the program that i've already have?

Comment: see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution

Comment: @egreg With an older TeX system's code, it doesn't show none of the letters. It seems just like not recognize Greek.

Comment: @giannis Are you sure you saved your document as UTF-8?

Comment: @egreg I think that I've saved properly my document.

Comment: @egreg For the past 3 weeks, I have been trying all these above both to my PC and to my laptop (which also is working with Windows OS) and I haven't managed to clear this out. Even your text above I couldn't make it as your output. I've tried both of these ways, but nothing...

Comment: @giannis Are you sure your editor is using UTF-8?

Comment: @egreg totally sure!

Comment: @egreg If I'm reading these READMEs correctly, with a sufficiently *new* TeXLive (2014 or later, I think), it should be `LGR` instead of `LGRx` in the fontenc settings.  Do you know if that's right?

Comment: @zwol Things have changed in the meantime! You should not need `LGR` anywhere. I added the details

Comment: Is there any solution for `Bengali` language also?

Comment: @alhelal It's better to switch to XeLaTeX for Bengali and other Indian languages.

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use XeLaTeX. In this case you need to install [CM-Unicode](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cm-unicode/) with the standard procedure of your Operating System (`C:\windows\fonts` catalog in windows `~/.fonts` in Linux etc)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{CMU Serif}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{CMU Sans Serif}
\setmonofont{CMU Typewriter Text}
\begin{document}
Κείμενο στα ελληνικά

Text in english
\end{document}
```

Alternatively you may use package `polyglossia` which is the replacement of `babel` for XeLaTeX but especially for the greek language, `xgreek` is probably a better choice. For more info look [here](http://www.mechpedia.gr/wiki/LaTeX) (section "Ελληνικά")

The main advantage of XeLaTeX over pdfLaTeX is that you can easily use native system fonts and that you can also use `ucharclasses` which is a package that will allow you to change hyphenation rules without explicitly declaring the languages (with the restriction that the involved languages must be members of different unicode blocks). You may find a minimum working example, plus some extra info [here](http://www.mechpedia.gr/wiki/Hyphenation_-_%CE%A5%CF%86%CE%B5%CE%BD%CF%8E%CF%83%CE%B5%CE%B9%CF%82)

Comment: I've noticed that the only text that I can have is only what you've written above. I don't know why... :/

Comment: That's really strange, but I am afraid that unless you provide some more info it is not going to be possible to get help... Perhaps you could open a new question with the specific problem, or at the very least upload the ``tex`` file and the ``log`` file. In any case, make sure that your tex distribution is updated and that you use the latest version of CM-Unicode.

Comment: I've recently updated them so as to achieve it. However, what I see as a result is only commas, full stops, and all the punctuation of the text, except for the text itself.

Comment: What operating system do you use? Make sure that the OS can see the fonts.  It sounds like they are not installed. In Windows you need to place them in `C:\Windows\fonts` directory. In Linux at `~.fonts` and run `fc-cache -fv`. Google it for more info.

Comment: I use the OS of Windows 7 and I am sure that I've placed the fonts in the appropriate file, just like as you noticed above.

Comment: I am afraid it is difficult to offer more help from here. Comments are not especially helpful for providing the necessary context. You should consider opening a new question, although mailing lists are probably more suitable than tex.stackexchange for this type of problems.

Comment: Just a couple of more suggestions. Make sure that you have saved the *.tex file in utf8. If you change font what happens? Try with arial or another font that comes installed with windows.

Answer (score 1):

Some times you have to write only some sections or words in Greek in this case  I found very useful the solution in this [Overleaf tutorial](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/I_want_to_write_Greek_language_text._How_do_I_do_this%3F):

```
%\title{Example: Greek and English text}
% based on
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110573/writing-greek-text
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\section{Εισαγωγή}

Σήμερα είδα για πρώτη φορά το
\selectlanguage{english} site
\selectlanguage{greek}του Γιάννη.

\[
a = b + \gamma
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Here (TeXlive 2020 on Fedora 34 beta) it is enough to use `utf8` for `inputenc`. For some reason, `utf8x` breaks `hyperref`.