# Writing Greek text

Tags: babel, greek

I am trying to compile some Greek text in PDF. I get it compiled using `babel` package, but text in Greek renders as complete gibberish. Only if I write Latin text does it convert it into Greek letters, but I have text in Greek to begin with.

Here are my two closest tries

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{otherlanguage}{greek}
ἀλλ' οὐ λέγουσι τὸ διὰ τί περὶ οὐδενός, οἷον διὰ
\end{otherlanguage}

\textgreek{ἀλλ' οὐ λέγουσι τὸ διὰ τί περὶ οὐδενός, οἷον διὰ}
```

and another one

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[iso-8859-7]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\section{Εισαγωγή}

Σήμερα είδα για πρώτη φορά το
\selectlanguage{english} site
\selectlanguage{greek}του Γιάννη.

\end{document}
```

output for both

```
ὐὤὐὡἑᾥᾠ ὓᾲἑᾢᾠὐᾥ
Ξ•Ξ ́ΗΟ•Ξ•Ξ•Ο•Ξ•Ξ•
```

Comment: Can you please add information on your TeX distribution, editor and operating system?

Comment: This question is very similar to [how can we write in Greek with computer modern font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100690), [How to typeset greek letters](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69901) and [Upright Greek letters in text mode (not upgreek)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9219). Please take a look at these questions as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
```

See http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf page 32 footnote.

Comment: The correct way to use this is to add `\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}` afterwards and whenever you want to include a piece of Greek then use things like `\textgreek{Κυβερνήτης}`

Comment: That does not work: it says Undefined control sequence \textgreek

Answer (score 13):

When you search this site, you could find quite a few answers to your question.

Personally, I would use LuaLaTeX. With LuaLaTeX you could just type Greek without any additional packages -- provided that you use a font that contains all the Greek characters (and accents) you are about to use. And: you don't need to learn new syntax or commands if you switch from LaTeX to LuaLaTeX.

For a document, that is completely in Greek:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatexmk
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Arial Unicode MS}

\begin{document}

πάντες ἄνθρωποι τοῦ εἰδέναι ὀρέγονται φύσει. σημεῖον δ᾽ ἡ τῶν αἰσθήσεων ἀγάπησις: 
καὶ γὰρ χωρὶς τῆς χρείας ἀγαπῶνται δι᾽ αὑτάς, καὶ μάλιστα τῶν ἄλλων ἡ διὰ τῶν 
ὀμμάτων. οὐ γὰρ μόνον ἵνα πράττωμεν ἀλλὰ καὶ μηθὲν μέλλοντες πράττειν τὸ ὁρᾶν 
αἱρούμεθα ἀντὶ πάντων ὡς εἰπεῖν τῶν ἄλλων. αἴτιον δ᾽ ὅτι μάλιστα ποιεῖ γνωρίζειν 
ἡμᾶς αὕτη τῶν αἰσθήσεων καὶ πολλὰς δηλοῖ διαφοράς. φύσει μὲν οὖν αἴσθησιν ἔχοντα 
γίγνεται τὰ ζῷα, ἐκ δὲ ταύτης τοῖς μὲν αὐτῶν οὐκ ἐγγίγνεται μνήμη, τοῖς δ᾽ ἐγγίγνεται.

\end{document}
```

And if you need both English and Greek:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatexmk
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Scale=MatchUppercase,Ligatures=TeX]{Arial Unicode MS}

\newcommand{\textgreek}[1]
    {\bgroup\greekfont{#1}\egroup} % Greek text

\newenvironment{greekpar}           % Greek paragraph
    {\greekfont}{}

\begin{document}

This is English with some Greek: \textgreek{γέγονεν}.

\begin{greekpar}
πάντες ἄνθρωποι τοῦ εἰδέναι ὀρέγονται φύσει. \textrm{And this is a Greek paragraph with some English.} σημεῖον δ᾽ ἡ τῶν αἰσθήσεων ἀγάπησις: καὶ γὰρ χωρὶς τῆς χρείας ἀγαπῶνται δι᾽ αὑτάς, καὶ μάλιστα τῶν ἄλλων ἡ διὰ τῶν ὀμμάτων. οὐ γὰρ μόνον ἵνα πράττωμεν ἀλλὰ καὶ μηθὲν μέλλοντες πράττειν τὸ ὁρᾶν αἱρούμεθα ἀντὶ πάντων ὡς εἰπεῖν τῶν ἄλλων. αἴτιον δ᾽ ὅτι μάλιστα ποιεῖ γνωρίζειν ἡμᾶς αὕτη τῶν αἰσθήσεων καὶ πολλὰς δηλοῖ διαφοράς. φύσει μὲν οὖν αἴσθησιν ἔχοντα γίγνεται τὰ ζῷα, ἐκ δὲ ταύτης τοῖς μὲν αὐτῶν οὐκ ἐγγίγνεται μνήμη, τοῖς δ᾽ ἐγγίγνεται.
\end{greekpar}

Isn't that quite nice? \textgreek{εὕρηκα!}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for showing how to have both languages in the same document!