# Cannot produce greek with utf8 and babel

Tags: babel, font-encodings, input-encodings, greek

I am creating a document in greek, using `babel` and `utf8` encoding. I am using `MiKTeX 2.9` and `TeXMakeR`. When trying to produce a document I get the error

```
Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:Γ not set up for use with LaTeX
```

My code is

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}

\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1,LGR]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
Γεια σου κόσμε!
\end{document}
```

Note that I have changed my editor's encoding in `utf8`. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: inputenc option `utf8` definitely doesn't work for greek; iirc, `utf8x` does cope with greek; however, if at all possible, you're better off using `xelatex`, which doesn't need any dances to make utf-8 work

Comment: Please, try updating all MiKTeX packages and try again removing the `LGR` option. Can you add `\listfiles` to your example, compile and add to your question what you'll find in the log file after `* File List *`?

Comment: @wasteofspace utf8 does work for Greek, provided the TeX distribution is up-to-date. [Here's](http://i.stack.imgur.com/P5QWu.png) the picture of the output I get from Qubit's code.

Comment: I have no problem compiling this. Perhaps the file was first  *not* utf8 encoded? Then asking for utf8 encoding set up a mess. Try retyping in a new file.

Comment: @Bernard The error message shows a Gamma, so that's not the problem.

Comment: I confirm that the code in the question works as intended with pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian).  Other than that, if you're planning to do anything serious with Greek text, I'd recommend `xelatex`.

Comment: or LuaLaTeX -- see this here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110604/12277