# Writing Solution environment in Greek

Tags: greek, mathematics

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}
\author{Athanasios Paraskevopoulos}
\date{December 2022}
\title{ODE}
\newenvironment{solution}
  {\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacksquare$}\begin{proof}[Solution]}
  {\end{proof}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

 \begin{solution}[of some exercise]
     
    \end{solution}



\end{document}
```

I usually write my exercises with the above code. However, now I want to send the exercises they give us at the university written in LaTeX and I would like it to be in Greek. Can someone help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome. // Search for greek here, in the search field on top, or click on tag greek. See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110604/245790 .

Comment: What MS-SPO said plus https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100690/, or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69901, or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9219.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? (is for `pdfLaTeX` and for Greek - English document with main language Greek). For `LuaLaTeX` or `XeLaTeX` is slightly different, let me know if you need it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage[T1,LGR]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\author{Αθανάσιος Παρασκευόπουλος}
\date{Δεκέμβριος 2022}
\title{ODE}
\newenvironment{solution}
{\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\blacksquare$}\begin{proof}[Λύση:]}
    {\end{proof}}

\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    
    \begin{solution}[Κάποιας άσκησης]
        
    \end{solution}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is very helpful