# My text's font style changes and goes to italic after using the Pi symbol

Tags: symbols

After using the Pi symbol (\Pi), my text changes to a different font and goes to italic. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Neither `\Pi` nor `\pi`  should even work in text mode, unless the command has been redefined and producing something ( completely different?)

Comment: Probably you forgot  a closing `$`. Could you post a minimal example?

Comment: If you want to write the mathematical symbol, try putting dollar signs around \pi. If you want to write text in the Greek language, not mathematics, consider http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100690/how-can-we-write-in-greek-with-computer-modern-font

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `$\Pi$`. In this case, math expressions have to be between dollar signs.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/93604)

Comment: @Romain Picot - Imho this provides an answer to the question.

Comment: It might be. However, since the OP does'nt provide any MWE, it could be due to a missing `$` or a redefinition of `\pi` as pointed by ChristianHupfer. My comment is more, that we should wait for clarification from the OP before to guess as solution

Comment: OK, I understand.

Comment: @RomainPicot: Perhaps some black magic with `\ensuremath` ... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The command for Π in text mode is `\textPi`, or you could put a literal Π in your UTF-8 source.

In a modern TeX engine that supports Unicode, you can load `fontspec` and a font that supports Greek.  In 8-bit TeX, you would want to add the packages

```
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textalpha}
```

and optionally change the font, or enable a LGR-encoded Greek font with `substitutefont`.