# Change language in a template

Tags: languages

I want to make a cv. I Found this [this](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/simple-cv/wmsyrgqwwqnc) (Simple CV) template I want to use but i can't change the language to Greek. I tried  using the command usepackage[ ]{babel} but didn't work can someone help ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The CV you link to is written in English, you need to rewrite it in Greek I assume

Comment: @JamesT how i can do that ? Using what command?

Comment: You do that by rewriting it in Greek, I am not aware of any LaTeX package that will translate English into Greek, `babel` and such offer support for languages, they won't rewrite hardcoded words although I may be wrong

Comment: @JamesT i am not trying to translate it ; I can't write in other language

Comment: @JamesT as i said babel doesn't work. If you can help me fix it .

Comment: To translate the template, just edit the files like `Simple-CV/languages.tex` and replace terms like `Turkish` by `Τουρκικά` and `Mother tongue, native speaker` by `Μητρική γλώσσα, μητρική γλώσσα` (don't know, if the terms are correct, I've just used Google translator). As already told `babel` is not a translator, it just stores several terms in macros and redefines them, depending on the selected language. Additionally it has code for some other language dependent rules like hyphenation etc. Because the template does not use (and provide) such macros, `babel` cannot really change the output.

Comment: @cabohah i dont think you understand. When i compile greek text like Τουρκία doesn't show up

Comment: Have you loaded `babel` with corresponding options? Can you show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964). See also: [how can we write in Greek with computer modern font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/100690/277964)